# How to use a Firebase emulator demo project in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I have a Flutter project where I use Firebase Authentication. I'd like to test it locally. Here is how Firebase local emulator is started:

```
firebase emulators:start --project demo-test --only auth
```

Here is Firebase initialization from `main.dart`:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: 'any',
    appId: 'any',
    messagingSenderId: 'any',
    projectId: 'demo-test',
  ));

  //...

  runApp(...);
}
```

Everything starts smoothly without errors. The app works. However when I try to sign up a new user:

```dart
firebase_auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
```

I receive an error:

```
[firebase_auth/unknown] com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key. ]
```

I suspect that I need to provide a proper API key for `demo-test` project but where can I find it? Or may be I can provide one when starting the emulator? I couldn't find answer in Google docs.

To clarify things. The app works fine when I use options of my real Firebase project. The problem comes only with a so-called Demo project.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Comment: It would be a great surprise if this suggestion worked. Cleaning and rebuilding does not help.

Comment: do you have the file : google-services.json in your project ?

Comment: It is a good question. How can I get one for the demo project?

Comment: Are you calling `useAuthEmulator` anywhere? https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/useAuthEmulator.html

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen! It kind of helped. After reading https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth I was under impression that you don't need to do that call in Flutter. Now I have another problem `[firebase_auth/unknown] com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Cleartext HTTP traffic to 10.0.2.2 not permitted ]`. Could you please hint me about it?

Comment: I've added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to AndroidManifest.xml. Not sure how correct is that but it helped. Please confirm when you have a moment. And please add your comment as an answer so I can resolve my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to call `useAuthEmulator` in your code before using the authentication service. The Flutter code for that may be missing from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth) (I just filed an issue to get it added there), but the API to call can be found [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/useAuthEmulator.html).

I'm don't exactly recall how I addressed that cleartext issue last time I encountered it, but am quite sure it was by following some top search results including the `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` that you mention.